# How to get build definition from TFS and pass it to the external program

Tags: tfs

How to get build definition from TFS and pass it to the external program

This is what we are doing manually:

1) Queue new build 
2) Once build is completed go to the drop folder and get the exe name 
3) pass this exe name to the test automation program and run it.`

I want to automate these 3 steps.
Is it possible to get the build definition programatically?

Comment: Also what your test tool might help too. I might have a different answer if you're using nUnit than if you're using Tekerik's test tool...

Comment: TFS 2010. We have stub program which calls the exe so test tool is not relevant here. I would like to know is it possible to get build artifacts prgramatically when queue new build is submittied in TFS. If it is possible then i will insert this piece of code into my stub program.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom Build Template. Use a copy of the default (or what ever you're using now) as your starting point. Look in the work flow where BuildDetail.CompilationStatus = BuildPhaseStatus.Succeeded. You will then have the opportunity to invoke another application, it would be a stub program/powershell script/any other executable process. you can pass the path of the build that you just completed by using BuildDetail.DropLocation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your step #1 has executed, this latest (successful!) build is reachable as the `lastKnownGoodBuild` of the specific build definition.
With this in mind you can employ a console app that bases on the following:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

namespace BuildDropLocation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://yourTFSServerUri"));

            var buildService = (IBuildServer)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

            IBuildDefinition myBuildDefinition = buildService.GetBuildDefinition("TeamProjectName", "BuildDefinitionName");
            Uri lastKnownGoodBuild = myBuildDefinition.LastGoodBuildUri;
            IBuildDetail myBuildDetail = buildService.GetBuild(lastKnownGoodBuild);
            string[] myExeFiles = Directory.GetFiles(myBuildDetail.DropLocation, "*.exe",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (var exeFile in myExeFiles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myExeFile);
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

With the above you can retrieve the path to any `*.exe` under the drop location of the last build of build definition `BuildDefinitionName` that lives in Team Project `TeamProjectName`.
This approach allows you to fully separate your TFS-Build with the execution of your tests. You can, for example, schedule this console-app to execute every night and invoke your runner to operate on the latest successful build.
In case you would like the build and the testrun to be coupled in any way, you should proceed as @TimWagaman suggests by invoking your test runner during build. This 'coupling' might include:

- The test results are contained in the build log
- A failure generates a Bug
- Test coverage is reportable

In this case, your tests will execute with each and every build that doesn't break in the compilation phase.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <MakeDir Directories="$(TemporaryFolder)" />
    <Exec Condition=" '$(IsInTeamBuild)'=='True'" Command="&quot;$(TfsTask)&quot; history ../ /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W > &quot;$(TemporaryFolder)\grab-changeset.txt&quot;" />
    <Exec Condition=" '$(IsInTeamBuild)'=='True'" Command="&quot;$(TfsTask)&quot; properties &quot;$(MyMSBuildStartupDirectory)\all-companies-run-after-update.js&quot; > &quot;$(TemporaryFolder)\grab-properties.txt&quot;" />
```

We use the above to extract: build#, branch, revision#
from the generated .txt files.